# How can I make image auto slider with dots for navigation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, animation

I have to implement a image slider which have following functionality:

1. It keeps auto rotating
2. and makes some dots over it for pagination

I dont want fadein fadeout type slider

What I have tried so far is given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>auto slider</title>
<style>
.container{width:1000px; height:100px; position:relative;}
.slide{width:1000px; height:100px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var slideWidth = 1000;
 startSlider();
 function startSlider() {

     looper = setInterval(function () {
            console.log("nishit");
           $('.slide').animate({
                'left': '-=' + (slideWidth) + 'px'
            }, 500); 

        },1000);
}

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="slide3">
   <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/5uxqi0mgl/cats1.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="slide">
   <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/5uxqi0mgl/cats4.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="slide">
   <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/5uxqi0mgl/cats6.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a ready made slider like [bxslider](http://bxslider.com)

Comment: i cant use fadein fadeout type slider i have mentioned this above i have to  use  jquery animate

Comment: if you look at the option page i.e. here http://bxslider.com/options. You'll see that it supports various modes apart from fade.

Comment: i cannt use bxslider or any other plugin